# Dropzone implementation in Aurelia not working in Component

Tags: dropzone.js, aurelia

I am trying to add dropzone to an Aurelia project. I followed the [example](https://github.com/jdanyow/aurelia-dropzone/blob/master/index.html) of Jeremy Danyow.

It all works fine when I'm setting up the project like his example project. But I don't want to put everything into the `main.js` and `main.html`.

So I tried to encapsulate the dropzone functionality into a reusable component and adding this component to the `main.html` view.

main.html

```
<template>
  <require from="dropzone/dropzone.min.css"></require>
  <require from="./components/dropzone"></require>
  <dropzone></dropzone>
</template>
```

components/dropzone.js

```
import dropzone from 'dropzone';

export class Dropzone {

  attached() {
    this.zone = new Dropzone(this.targetElement, { url: "/file/post"});
  }
}
```

components/dropzone.html

```
<template>
  <h2>Dropzone from components/dropzone.js</h2>
  <form class="dropzone" ref="targetElement"></form>
</template>
```

added dependency to aurelia.json

```
          "dropzone",
          {
            "name": "dropzone",
            "path": "../node_modules/dropzone/dist/min",
            "main": "dropzone.min",
            "resources": [
              "dropzone.min.css"
            ]
          }
```

Unfortunately this isn't working anymore.

What is missing in my code?

[See the project in my git account](https://github.com/neonnoe/Aurelia-Dropzone-Component)

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: i tried to install dropzone by `npm install dropzone` and then `import Dropzone from 'dropzone';` but it throws 404 error. Is am missing any thing to install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class exported by the `dropzone` module is named `Dropzone` (per your comment below). Given this, you'll need to change your own class name. I'd recommend `DropzoneCustomElement`. Let me know if this works:

main.html

```
<template>
  <require from="dropzone/dropzone.min.css"></require>
  <require from="./components/dropzone"></require>
  <dropzone></dropzone>
</template>
```

components/dropzone.js

```
import Dropzone from 'dropzone';

export class DropzoneCustomElement {

  attached() {
    this.zone = new Dropzone(this.targetElement, { url: "/file/post"});
  }
}
```

components/dropzone.html

```
<template>
  <h2>Dropzone from components/dropzone.js</h2>
  <form class="dropzone" ref="targetElement"></form>
</template>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but `new Dropzone(...)` is the Class name in the `dropzone.js` file. My implementation with capital "D" works fine when creating this class directly from `main.js`. You can see this in the linked GIT. If I understood correctly, I import `dropzone` (small "d") because it is exactly how I named the dependency in `aurelia.json`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick answer, Ashley. This was exactly the problem. Now, it's working fine.

Comment: Hey @ChristophNoe, am in need of implement Dropzone, but no idea how to start, do we need to install Dropzone through jspm ?

Comment: Hi @sibi, I use Aurelia CLI in my project. If you installed dropzone with `npm install --save`, check if the files are in the folder "node_modules". You then have to create the reference in the file `aurelia_project/aurelia.json`. You can see how it is done in the initial question above. After that, the import should not thorw a 404 error.

Comment: Also check, if your import statement is `import dropzone from 'dropzone';`. No capilal "D".