# Adding 3rd-party JavaScript library (dropzone.js) to Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia, dropzone.js

I'm having a lot of trouble figuring out how to add a 3rd-party JavaScript library to Aurelia (in this case dropzone.js).

I've installed dropzone via npm and configured it in aurelia.json:

```
{
  "name": "dropzone",
  "path": "../node_modules/dropzone/dist/min",
  "main": "dropzone.min",
  "resources": [
    "dropzone.min.css"
  ]
}
```

And added the require statement for the CSS to my app.html:

```
<require from="dropzone/dropzone.min.css"></require>
```

However, when I try to do a simple test like just putting the HTML directly in my template, the functionality does not work.

```
<template>
  <form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone" id="my-awesome-dropzone"></form>
</template>
```

I've also tried this solution but couldn't get it working as well: [Dropzone implementation in Aurelia not working in Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983754/dropzone-implementation-in-aurelia-not-working-in-component)

Comment: Are you getting any errors? The answer you've posted should have worked

Comment: No I'm not getting any errors.  When I try to drag an image into the box that displays, the browser just opens the image.  I think the problem is that the .dropzone element is not getting initialized by the JavaScript.  Also, if I click on the box nothing happens whereas with the example from the dropzone.js site, the file uploader box should appear.

Comment: Did you import it in the view model?

Comment: I've tried `import Dropzone from 'dropzone';`, `import {Dropzone} from 'dropzone';` and `import * from 'dropzone';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It won't work according to your example simply because the dropzone.js library code is loaded before your view-model is activated, and Aurelia won't re-trigger it.  You'll need to manually activate dropzone.js within your `attached()` method in your viewmodel, like this:

```
// JQuery option
$("div#myId").dropzone({ url: "/file/post" });

// Non-JQuery option
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myId", { url: "/file/post"});
```

Therefore, your view-model might look like this:

**file-upload.js**

```
export class FileUpload {

  attached() {
    // activate dropzone.js element
    this.zone = new Dropzone(this.dz, { url: "/file/post"});
  }

  detached() {
    // deactivate the element
    this.zone.destroy();
  }

}
```

**file-upload.html**

```
<template>
  <form ref="dz" action="/file-upload" class="dropzone">
    <div class="fallback">
      <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
    </div>
  </form>
</template>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works! This makes sense now that you explained it.  For it to work with the code as setup in the question, I added the following code: `attached() { $('.dropzone').dropzone({url: '/post'}); }`

Comment: this step was explained in the answer you've mentioned in your question...

Comment: I'm glad it worked.  I added sample code to make it more clear.

Comment: @LStarkey dropzone has destroy method, not in doc, but in their source code. This is what I do in detached. `detached() { if (this.zone) { this.zone.destroy(); this.zone = null; } }`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `import 'dropzone';` to your view-model.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `dropzone-amd-module.min`. Like this:

```
{
  "name": "dropzone",
  "path": "../node_modules/dropzone/dist/min",
  "main": "dropzone-amd-module.min", 
  "resources": [
    "dropzone.min.css"
  ],
  "deps": ["jquery"]
}
```

Then, `import Dropzone from 'dropzone';` like in the other answer

Comment: No this doesn't work either.  I restarted `au run --watch` to be sure.  The weird thing is is that if I look at the vendor-bundle.js file, I see the dropzone.js code in there so I don't know why it isn't working.

Comment: put a breakpoint in the attached method, see if `Dropzone` is not undefined

Comment: Yes, I set a breakpoint in the constructor and typed `Dropzone` in the console.  It is not defined.

Comment: Dropzone is dependant on jQuery. Are you sure you have loaded jQuery?