# File Upload with Aurelia Example?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, aurelia

Can anyone show me a good example of doing a file upload with Aurelia ? I have yet to really see a good example . (html and javascript(or typescript for that matter))

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Jason

Comment: Show us what you have tried, or found, then we can help a little easier.

Comment: Also is this question about the client side implementation, or the server side (or both)? Here is an aurelia plugin to simplify things on the client side using html5 file reader https://github.com/grofit/aurelia-files

Comment: Check out dropzone and its implementation in Aurelia here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41107830/adding-3rd-party-javascript-library-dropzone-js-to-aurelia

Answer (score 0):

New to Aurelia so having a bit of a hard time getting the examples to work. I may not be doing the jspm intall correctly or maybe there is just something I'm not understanding. 
 To answer Alex's question , I already have a server side WebApi method that takes in the requests and looks at posted files and processes them. I have tested this with Chrome Postman . So my concern is strictly client side.  Below is my typescript class along with the corresponding . Basically I need the upload() method code to make the request to the api I believe. below is my typescript and corresponding html.

```
import 'fetch';
import {HttpClient, json} from 'aurelia-fetch-client';
import {inject} from 'aurelia-dependency-injection';

declare var window: { wcApiUrl: string, wcAmtInstanceId: string };

@inject(HttpClient)
export class BureauModUpdate {

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
        http.configure(x => {
            x.defaults.headers = { 'Authorization': 'Basic ' + window.wcAmtInstanceId }
        });
    }


    public upload(): void {

}
```

```html
<template>
    <require from="../converters"></require>
    <form novalidate name="runForm" style="border:solid">
        <div class="row data-form">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                <label>Select Bureau</label>
                <select id="BureauSelect" >
                    <option value="00">Ncci</option>
                    <option value="1">CA</option>
                    <option value="2">NY</option>
                    <option value="3">PA</option>
                    <option value="5">DE</option>
                    <option value="6">WI</option>
                    <option value="7">MI</option>
                    <option value="8">MN</option>  
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row data-form">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                <label>Select File Upload</label>
                <input type="file" name="upload" files.bind="files">
            </div>
        </div>
      

        <div class="row data-form">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
              
            </div>
        </div>
        <br /><br />
        <div class="row data-form">
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                <input type="submit">
            </div>
        </div>

    </form> 

</template>​
```

Jason